# number palindrome TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, numbers

I want to create a new list with a list of numbers, and in the new list, there can only be palindrome numbers.

```
l = [34, 435, 343, 765, 87878, 25752]


nwelist = [343, 87878, 25752]
```

What i tried:

```
d = []
l = [34, 435, 343, 765, 87878, 25752]
for i in l:
    if str(i)[0:len(l)//2] == i[len(l)//2:-1]:
        d.append(i)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Caitlin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/continue.py", line 4, in <module>
if str(i)[0:len(l)//2] == i[len(l)//2:-1]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue giving you an error is that on the right hand side of your `==` you have `i[len(l)//2:-1]` where you should have `str(i)[len(l)//2:-1]`. However there are other problems as well. Since you need to use `i` as a string, I suggest converting it up front, and also pre-computing the length. Then you can simplify the palindrome checking code:

```
d = []
l = [34, 435, 343, 765, 87878, 25752]
for i in l:
    s = str(i)
    ln = len(s)
    if s[0:ln//2] == s[ln-1:ln//2:-1]:
        d.append(i)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
[343, 87878, 25752]
```

Note this fixes the bugs in your code, but I would definitely recommend using  the code in @YOBEN_S answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

Check with

```
d = [x for x in l if str(x)==str(x)[::-1]]
[343, 87878, 25752]
```

Comment: Awsome! What dos [::-1] do?

Comment: @joshua reverse the order :-) like 123 become 321

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use `filter` and create a condition:

```
my_list = [34, 435, 343, 765, 87878, 25752]

[*filter(lambda x: str(x) == str(x)[::-1], my_list)]
```

```
[343, 87878, 25752]
```